# eclipse svn client doubles the file path

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, svnkit

i hit a strange error today with my eclipse subversion client. i want to update a file but instead i got a message:

```
*** Update
svn update "/home/ulkas/Develop/Beautyportal/app/views/partials" -r HEAD --depth infinity
    U /home/ulkas/Develop/Beautyportal/app/views/partials/footer.blade.php
svn: File not found: revision 34, path '/app/views/partials/app/views/partials/main-nav.blade.php'
*** Error (took 00:01.153)
```

watch the path `/app/views/partials/app/views/partials/main-nav.blade.php` - its being doubled, it shall be instead just `/app/views/partials/main-nav.blade.php`.

when i do a fresh checkout, it works, but in my original project this shows up. my configs:

```
linux mint 13 64bit.
eclipse 3.7.2
Subversive SVN Connectors   2.2.2.I20110124-1700
Subversive SVN Team Provider (Incubation)   0.7.9.I20110207-1700
SVNKit 1.3.5 Implementation (Optional)  2.2.2.I20110124-1700
```

Comment: Have you tried a `clean`?

Comment: yes, also restarts and other general stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SVNKit 1.3.5 Implementation (Optional)  2.2.2.I 20110124-1700

Your components, e.g. SVNKit are too outdated. I suggest upgrading SVNKit, Subversive at al and see whether it helps.

Comment: i couldn't push the eclipse to update the package so i ended up by manually installing newest `eclipse 4.4` + installing newer `jre 1.7` + installing the `svnKit 1.8.6` + installing appropriate `subversive` package and the checkout than when OK finally.

Answer (score 0):

i've ended by completely deleted project with a brand new svn checkout. solved this issue.

**Edit:** that is just a temporary solution, the error pops up again